# Why "-n" is commonly used for dry-run?

Tags: command, naming-conventions, conventions

Well known commands like `make`, `rsync`, and, `git` use `-n` option for dry-run.
What does `-n` stand for in this context?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that it's because *dry-run* contains the letter *n* and because *d* and *r* are already used:

```
$ make --help | grep '^ *-[dr]'
  -d                          Print lots of debugging information.
  -r, --no-builtin-rules      Disable the built-in implicit rules.
$ rsync --help | grep '^ *-[dr]'
 -r, --recursive             recurse into directories
 -d, --dirs                  transfer directories without recursing
```